# ArrayList cannot resolve symbol, after implent XML

Tags: android

My problem is that I declared my Array name in arrays.xml, but Android Studio still not recognize it, and gives me red for the array name, here's the code.

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myArray">
        <item name="yes">Yes</item>
        <item name="no">No</item>
        <item name="maybe">maybe</item>
        <item name="good">good</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In my main Activity the R.array.myArray gives me "cannot resolve symbol "myArray" ", what to do? I resynchronized my project, reloaded it, and restarted my comp, even cleared the cache too, but Android Studio still not recognized it, I tried to add it manually as a arrays.xml, and with alt+enter too.

```
public class MainActivity3 extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);


        Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText(q);
    }
```

I want to create an application, that gives you a random text, when an activity starts.

Comment: it looks good to me. Do you have the correct R import?

Comment: What should I add in the R.?

Comment: nothing. R is auto generated if your res/ folder has no issues. Check the import section of your Activity, you should find something like `your.packagename.R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        Resources res = getResources();
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(q);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this code is fine and it will run once and set the text1 or tv from myArray one time only when ever you run the app it will show you the random value set to text1 or tv in you app.... because you have written the code in oncreate() function which will call once only through out the life cycle of activity.

or wana use setOnClickListener on tv or button so when ever you click on that it will change the text of it. and  before writing  this code please change the declaration of tv as class variable or but final keyword in front of it
 and add this code below tv.setText(q);

```
tv.setText("click me please"); 
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                   
                     String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
                     testtv.setText(q);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Resources res = getResources();
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
```

this is correct code.

please check your arrays.xml file where you have kept it.
if you have kept in the value folder then no problem will occur it will work.

or you can put the code of  arrays.xml (i.e. declare and initialization of myArray ,as it is copy paste it)into string.xml which is in value folder and it will solve your problem.

As per your code you have extends ActionBarActivity

```
public class MainActivity3 extends ActionBarActivity
```

so please check the other dependence related to this ActionBarActivity

1. whether you have minsdkversion should be 11 or not.
2. if not then check whether you have supported library
   (android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity) for this or not and  set
   the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme
3. change the extends to Activity class instead  of  ActionBarActivity
       then please remove the the line from menu.xml as "shown" attribute 
       and comment the code of onCreateOptionsMenu code in your activity
       class other then this code

   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_to_know_your_own_number_main,
               menu);
       return true;

also delete a folder name "crunch" in "res" folder also from bin folder and clean the project its done

Comment: Everything is okay now, atleast in Android studio....When I put my app on my phone, it's force close when I want to go to MainActivity3 screen. And the mainactivity3 screen is where is the random text generator code. What is the problem? Makes me go mad.

public void ButtonOnClick1 (View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);
    }

Comment: I changed it to Activity intstead of ActionBarActivity, but somehow nothing happens, the text not change to the given string names, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: ok good ,public void ButtonOnClick1 (View v) { Button button = (Button) v; setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3); }   why are you using this code and where....mean in which activity your if you want  to change the text on click event then you just write that code only

Comment: if you want  to change the set random  text on click event then you just write that code only like "ButtonOnClick1 (View v) {String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];  tv.setText(q);}  TextView tv;"     and  remove the TextView from  tv in your oncreate() function

Answer (score 0):

It should be `myString = res.getStringArray(R.arrays.myArray);`

Answer (score 0):

First, can you please tell where are you storing the XML file ?

Second, I think you should remove the name attribute for each of the items in the array.

Comment: It's in the values folder, as an arrays.xml. Actually now it's working, I dont know what i'm did, but now there is no errors.

The biggest problem is now, that i'm start the application and it's force close. And I'm don't know why, what is the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ButtonOnClick1 (View v) {
      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
      String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
      tv.setText(q);
}
```

I click on the button, and application force close... I have no idea what's wrong.